# API call in SwiftUI getting a blank response

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, swiftui

I'm making an Xcode project involving an API call. When I make the call and try to access a certain part of the JSON file I can't seem to get it to work. When I try to print the data I fetch it just prints a blank row. I'm guessing I've done something wrong when I'm trying to accessing the data and pass it onto the `travelTime`variable. You can find the JSON data by following the URL string in the code below.

I also get this message in my Xcode console and I don't know why and if it's related to the problem.
`nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed`

I'm a beginner at Swift so I've been following tutorials online, but I can't find what I have done wrong in my code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var travelTime = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Time:\(travelTime)")
        Button("FetchAPI"){FetchAPI()}
    }
    
    func FetchAPI() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://api.sl.se/api2/TravelplannerV3_1/trip.xml?key=40892db48b394d3a86b2439f9f3800fd&originExtId=300101416&destExtId=300101426&Date=2021-04-15&Time=08:00&searchForArrival=1")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedJson = try? JSONDecoder().decode(JSONStructure.self, from: data) {
                    self.travelTime = decodedJson.Trip[0].LegList.Leg[0].Origin.time
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        print(self.travelTime)
    }
}


struct JSONStructure: Decodable {
    let Trip: [TripStructure]
}

struct TripStructure: Decodable {
    let LegList: LegListStructure
}

struct LegListStructure: Decodable {
    let Leg: [LegStructure]
}

struct LegStructure: Decodable {
    let Origin: OriginStructure
}

struct OriginStructure: Decodable {
    let time: String
}
```

Comment: Is `self.travelTime = decodedJson.Trip[0].LegList.Leg[0].Origin.time` called? When it happens, what's the value of `self.travelTime` afterwards? The correct value you expect?

Comment: I guess it's not called at all. Why ? because `decodedJSON` is nil, `decode(_:from:)` throws an error (that you are ignoring with `try?`, instead of doing a good `do`/`try`/`catch`). That could be also see if you `print("Response String: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`. Finally, you did `print(self.travelTime)`, but you are missing the asynchrone concept. Add a print where you do `if let data`, which one is called first? Which one did you expect to be called first?

Comment: @Larme Sorry, this is my first swift project so I'm not so familiar with that. Could you put that in simpler terms for me...? I wanted the `self.travelTime = decodedJson.Trip[0].LegList.Leg[0].Origin.time` to be called first. When I put the print statement inside of ìf let data` the output remains blank. Sorry if I misunderstood what you were trying to say in any way

Comment: Step: Your Web API is returning XML (it even has in its URL `trip.xml`), not JSON. JSON is not XML. If your WepAPI really can returns JSON, look how to do so. Since it's not JSON, `JSONDecoder().decode(JSONStructure.self, from: data)` will always fail. Overcome that one first. Also, add prints to know what's called, when it's called, etc;

Comment: @Larme OMG, of course, I copied the wrong URL. I have now changed it to `trip.json` and it works perfectly. Can't believe I missed that, haha. Thanks a lot for pointing that out! And thanks for the help!

Comment: Your print statement will very likely still print nil. You need to move that print statement inside your dataTask's completion handler.

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah, the print statement was just a way for me to check if it worked, but now it does so I just removed it. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, the print statement won't work were you show it in your post. (The code invokes the `resume()` command, then immediately executes the next statement (your print statement) before the network request has even been sent. Any code that depends on the network result must go in your completion handler.